# Handling WinJS app upon relaunch

Tags: winjs

When back home is pressed app exists but it is not terminated yet.
When user press primary or secondary tile app is relauched.

Default way is to let application navigate to the last visited page in the navigation history.
I don't know if there is a bug but this way doesn't work as expected because any code inside page ready function executes but it doesn't count later when page is rendered. Static binding works but not dynamic.

I need to know what is the proper way of handling relaunch in an app that uses default navigation template?

What to do if I want clean start, destroy everything and than navigate to home?

How to overcome problem with framework not taking into consideration code inside page ready function?

Answer (score 0):

Upon app initialization you should check for the [ApplicationExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate.aspx), and do whatever you want in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but it is quite clear from the start how to obtain ApplicationExecutionState.

Actually what I need was to execute all bindings and other post processing after DOM has been loaded in a promise timeout.

```
        if (app.sessionState.previousExecutionState === 1) {
            WinJS.Promise.timeout().then(function () {
                performeAfterProcessing();
            });
        }
        else {
            performeAfterProcessing();
        }
```

So if everyone encounters some strange behavior after application has been relaunched try to execute your code using promise timeout.